# ¿Cómo realizar un MATCH con dos o más columnas en SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Estoy siguiendo el ejemplo de Google [Storing and Searching for Data](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/search/search.html)

como buscar en una base de datos y devolver los resultados de un viewSearch, todo me funciona perfectamente, pero solo busca en una columna `COL_WORD`

```
public Cursor getWordMatches(String queryStr, String[] columns) {
    String selection = "" + COL_WORD + " MATCH ? ";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { queryStr + "*," };
    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
}

private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    builder.setTables(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);

    Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
            columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

Me gustaría adaptar el código que buscará dentro de los campos `COL_WORD` y `COL_DEFINITION` con condición `OR`, es decir que si la palabra a buscar se encuentra en un campo o otro o bien ambos, devuelve resultado.

Estoy mirando la documentación de [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#termprefix), me parece que la solución recae aquí, pero no tengo suficientes conocimientos para trasladarlo a objeto `SQLiteQueryBuilder`

> -- Query the database for documents for which the term "linux" appears in
>   -- the document title, and the term "problems" appears in either the title
>   -- or body of the document. SELECT * FROM docs WHERE docs MATCH 'title:linux problems';
>
> -- Query the database for documents for which the term "linux" appears in
>   -- the document title, and the term "driver" appears in the body of the document
>   -- ("driver" may also appear in the title, but this alone will not satisfy the.
>   -- query criteria). SELECT * FROM docs WHERE body MATCH 'title:linux driver';

Answer (score 1):

Para que busque dentro de los dos campos mencionados:

Dentro de `columns` deben ser definidas las columnas correspondientes a: `COL_WORD` y `COL_DEFINITION`
y tu string de selección:

```
 String selection = " MATCH ? OR MATCH ?";
```